# Finding maximum and minimum x, y-axis value of visible chart area

Tags: echarts

Finding maximum and minimum x, y-axis value of visible chart area.
use case: on click of button need to draw a line on the chart. I am following this example for the same https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-draggable

setting data for the series as

```
var data = [[10, 40], [10, 10]];
```

but as my chart is zoomable how do i get maximum and minimum x, y-axis value of visible chart area, so that i can compute coordinate for the line on run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate visible area, this is chart's task. To get the desired result you need [to known two API methods](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.convertToPixel):

1. `convertFromPixel` — convert canvas coordinates to chart coordinates.
2. `convertToPixel` — convert chart coordinates to canvas coordinates.

It detailed explain in [the official example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-pen): by mouse click cursor coordinates transform to chart's coords and then adding to series data for draw line.