# how to create a time chart in echarts

Tags: charts, visualization, echarts

I'd like to create a time chart 
more or less like the chrome devTool's network panel \

[image]

consider each row is a machine in a cluster 
then from left to right the time passes 
each rectangular box is a time span

### Question 1: what is the best way to do this in echarts?

### Question 2: how can I get the effective width? i.e. the hard coded `551`

I'm currently doing it using `type:scatter`, using symbolSize to draw the rectangles 
`const effectiveWidth=551`
`symbolSize: function (val) { return [val[2]*effectiveWidth/(data.max-data.min),10]; }`

[image]

-- EDIT --

waterfall chart(helpfully pointed out by the comment https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/how-to/chart-types/bar/waterfall/) seems working, I initially didn't choose it because I have to create a shadow series(transparent, stacked) for each and every series. is there a way to directly control where each rectangle is placed(like scatter chart)?

for Question2, sorry I should have mentioned `dataZoom`, when zooming, the `effective width` changes, but it is not reflected using `convertToPixel("grid",...)`, maybe I shouldn't be using "grid"?

I was using the following code(ec is an echart instance):

```
const computeScale=(w)=>(ec.convertToPixel("grid",[w,0])[0]-ec.convertToPixel("grid",[0,0])[0])/w
symbolSize: (val)=>[Math.max(0,(scale??=computeScale(86400000))*zoomScale*val[2]-1),10],
```

but it has some flaws:

1. the symbol size is in pixel, the `val`(intended width) is in value(xAxis), thus the conversion is needed. can we tell echart to somehow use the same coordinate system directly without the conversion?
2. when zooming, the above conversion(using `convertToPixel`) doesn't work, thus I have to introduce another `zoomScale` value `let zoomScale=1;ec.on("datazoom",(ev:any)=>void(zoomScale=100/(ev.end-ev.start)))`(BTW `ev.start` and `ev.end` is double value, not integer, so it shouldn't have too much precision problem, but it do have
3. all these conversion have precision problems, especially `zoomScale`, it often creates rect overlapping artifacts

https://stackblitz.com/edit/qwik-starter-dhqv1i?file=src/routes/index.tsx

zoom using the handles at the bottom of the preview page to see the artifacts

Comment: 1: as the column header indicates in your screenshot, that is a Waterfall chart. https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/how-to/chart-types/bar/waterfall/ which you want drawn horizontally https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack  and 
2: sounds like you're looking for min and max of x axis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448984/finding-maximum-and-minimum-x-y-axis-value-of-visible-chart-area 
have you read the echarts documentation? https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/get-started/

Comment: @pthomson Hi, thanks for the reply, I've appended the `--EDIT--` section, and added a preview link that you can view directly